# React native chart for streaming real-time data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, react-native, charts, linechart

This post is more of a question instead of a problem. So please feel free to let me know if this is not the right place to ask.

I'm currently using react-native, and my application is receiving real-time data of values between -0 to 1 values. These data need to be represented in a line chart, this [`example`](http://joakimkemeny.github.io/jke.d3.ecg/) pretty much explains what I want.

The issue is, I'm not really sure which library in react native would be most suitable for showing real-time data.

Any help and advice would be appreciated.

Ps: The line chart looks very simple, so if it can be done from scratch, that would be a bonus because I'd have to only render the line. However I'm not entirely sure about the implementation in react-native.

## Update

I found [`this`](https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts) which kind of resembles what I want. But there's an interval between each point.

Comment: Hello, did you find anything for this yet? If so please share your findings.

Answer (score 3):

you can use any charting package I'm using [react-native-svg-charts](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts).

To visualize "real-time" data you basically have an array of data points through which you "shift" to get the flowing of the graph.

How you realize this is up to you. To get rid of the visual "interval" you just have to update at a higher rate e.g. 30 times per second = 30 fps.

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try to do that the next time I give an answer :)